# Use Axis 1.1 in Eclipse Juno

Tags: c#, java, eclipse, wsdl, axis

I am forced to use Axis 1.1 in my Java Application to create a stub for a Asp.net C# WSDL. The reason for this is that the external WSDL uses method overloading, which is not supported in Axis versions later than 1.1. However, there does not seem te be an option to downgrade the Axis version in Eclipse Juno. Axis 2 has an input field which contains the location for your Axis 2 folder, but Axis 1.x does not seem to offer this feature.

Can someone explain how I can downgrade from the Juno Axis version (1.4?) to Axis 1.1?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the wizard that creates the axis stubs you can not override that easily. It will be much less painful if you generate the stubs outside eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What would you use to create the stubs?

Comment: I don't think you really need to use axis 1.1. Can we have your wsdl ?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to share it. I do understand this means helping me is quite hard, but I hope it is still possible. The only reason why Axis 1.1 seems to be the only choice is because of the method overloading. if there is another tool that supports this, I would like to hear about it

Answer (score 0):

See an excellent tutorial in [Axis 1.x Client Stub Generation](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CROWDDEV/Axis+1.x+Client+Stub+Generation). You see a command like the next:

```
java -cp "$AXISCLASSPATH" org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java myService.wsdl
```

For that, you need to donwload the Axis 1 Runtime from [Apache Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis/).

Additionally, you can see the [*oficial guide*](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2Java%3a_Building_stubs_skeletons_and_data_types_from_WSDL) in Apache page.